# Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=3 with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im getting this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhLFx.jpg
I can create comments in mi course post but i can't edit them because of this error

I don't know how to solve this, I was looking everywhere but nothing that helps me solve the problem

**EDIT**
here is my code in comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @comment = @course.comments.build
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @comment = @course.comments.build(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

so i think the problem might be in create and new, i dont know how to connect the models with one-to-many, i was able to create comments in my course but when i wanted to edit 1 of the comments apiers that error and in every comment i click to edit sends me to the same url with the same error id=3 not found

Also this are my html code(maybe the errors can be there too):

```
<%= form_for @comment, :url => course_comments_path(params[:course_id]) do |f| %>
  <% if comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, id: :comment_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, id: :comment_body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the show.html for my courses:

```
<% if current_user%>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <h1><%= @course.name %></h1>
</p>

<p>
    <h2>Comentarios del curso:</h2> 
</p>
<p>     
    <% @course.comments.each do |comment| %>

            <h3><%= comment.title %></h3>         
            <p><%= comment.body %></p>
            <%if current_user.admin%>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_comment_path(@course) %>
            <%end%>
    <%end%>
</p>


<%if current_user.admin %>

    <%= link_to 'Postear', new_course_comment_path(@course)%>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_comment_path%>
    <%= link_to 'Back',  authenticated_root_path %>


<%else%>
    <%= link_to 'Postear', new_course_comment_path(@course) %>
    <%= link_to 'Back',  authenticated_root_path %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Can you show the routes?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VDS6t9G AkshayGoyal here

Comment: This image doesn't contain routes specific to comments. You can share the specific portion of your routes.rb file.

Comment: sorry mb this are the routes to comments https://imgur.com/a/HLA9jXx

Comment: Your routes look fine to me. Are you sure comment with id=3 exists in your db?

Comment: i was looking at the app and i found that every comment i create is being redirect to the same url when pressing edit_comment,  not sure why:(

Comment: That is difficult to tell unless you share your code. Anyway, there's a slight improvement that can be done in your code. Instead of using `Comment.find(params[:id])`, it should be `Course.find(params[:course_id]).comments.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: Can you please code and paste the code into the post directly instead of linking to images. That allows searching within the code and to copy parts of it into an answer.

Comment: yes, now i posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you have a strange mix of [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter#shallow-nesting) and deep nesting. Shallow nesting is a routing option that effects the nesting of member routes.

```
resources :courses do
  # GET|PUT|PATCH|DELETE /courses/:course_id/comments/:id
  # GET /courses/:course_id/comments/:id/edit
  resources :comments
  # GET|PUT|PATCH|DELETE /comments/:id
  # GET /comments/:id/edit
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
```

I would generally recommend shallow nesting - unless the child only can exist in the scope of its parent or is only unique in the scope of its parent. And your controller is setup for shallow nesting. Just make sure you edit those comments from the scaffold so that they actually document the right paths.

Besides the routes you also need to use the correct link helpers:

```
# deep nesting
link_to 'Edit', edit_course_comment_path(@course, @comment)

# shallow nesting
link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(@comment)
```

If you really need to support both you can use the polymorpic route helpers:

```
link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @course, @comment]
```

To create forms for nested resources pass an array containing the parent and child:

```
form_for([@course, @comment])
# or in rails 5+
form_with(model: [@course, @comment])
```

This works perfectly fine with both deep and shallow nesting as well as Rails compacts the array. This also lets you use the same form partial for creating and updating.

Explicitly passing the URL for a form in Rails is redundant 99% of the time. If you just follow the conventions Rails is smart enough to figure out the correct path for creating and updating.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line

```
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_comment_path(@course) %>
```

should be

```
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_comment_path(@course, comment) %>
```

You need both ids of the course and the comment.